# 3D polynomial fit

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I have a set of data that I'd like to fit using the following 3D-polynomial:

```
y = c1 + c2 * u + c3 * v + c4 * u² + c5 * (u*v) + c6 * v² + c7 * u³ + c8 *  (v * u²) + c9 * (u * v²) + c10 * v³
```

I tried with `curve_fit` but it only works with given dataset. Any points between the given data would give a wrong `ZZ`.
Is there a better solution to this?

Any help would be appreciated!

The code:

```
import numpy as np
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import scipy

def fnc(u, v, params):
    c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10 = params
    return c1 + c2 * u + c3 * v + c4 * u**2 + c5 * (u*v) + c6 * v**2 + c7 * u**3 + c8 * ( v * u**2 ) + c9 * (u * v**2) + c10 * v**3

def fn(params, f, u, v):
    c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10 = params
    return np.ravel(c1 + c2*u + c3*v + c4*u**2+c5*(u*v)+c6*v**2+c7*u**3+c8*(v*u**2)+c9*(u*v**2)+c10*v**3-f)

x = np.transpose(np.array([-25.0,-20.0,-15.0,-10.0,-5.0,0.0,5.0,10.0]))
y = np.transpose(np.array([40.0,50.0,60.0]))
XX,YY = np.meshgrid(x,y)
XX = np.transpose(XX)
YY = np.transpose(YY)

ZZ = np.transpose(np.array([[3878.00,4636.00,5489.00,6483.00,7616.00,8844.00,10245.00,11865.00],[3712.00,4298.00,5123.00,6004.00,7030.00,8161.00,9503.00,11004.00],[3548.00,4064.00,4707.00,5529.00,6434.00,7506.00,8716.00,10070.00]]))

p0 = [0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5]

print 'XX', XX
print ''
print 'YY', YY
print ''
print 'ZZ', ZZ
print ''

#fitParams, fitCovariances = curve_fit(fn,x0=p0,args=(ZZ,XX,YY),full_output=1)
pfit, pcov, infodict, errmsg, success = scipy.optimize.leastsq(fn,x0=p0,args=(ZZ,XX,YY),full_output=1)

for i in range(len(pfit)):
    print 'c'+str(i+1), '%0.3e' % pfit[i], '%0.3e' % np.absolute(pcov[i][i])**0.5
print ''

#print pcov
#print errmsg
#print success

u = -8.
v = 53.
print 'u', u
print 'v', v
amp = fnc(u, v, pfit)
print 'Value with fitted parameters:', amp
```

Comment: Could you please explain more what you mean by "it only works with given dataset"?

Comment: a wrong ZZ, sorry ...

Comment: it only works with data in x and y. For ex. :x = -25; y = 40.

Comment: I tried with u = -8 and v = 53 (see last part of the code), it gave a completely wrong value with fitted parameters...

Comment: What would be the "correct" result for u=-8, v=53?

Comment: this is the results I get:

Comment: u -8.0
v 53.0
Value with fitted parameters: 2616.35010015
>>>

Comment: but it should be a little higher than 6000

Comment: Could you explain why it should be a little higher than 6000?  You are looking at the next values on the four points next to (-8,53)?

Comment: XX [[-25. -25. -25.]
 [-20. -20. -20.]
 [-15. -15. -15.]
 [-10. -10. -10.]
 [ -5.  -5.  -5.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [  5.   5.   5.]
 [ 10.  10.  10.]]

YY [[ 40.  50.  60.]
 [ 40.  50.  60.]
 [ 40.  50.  60.]
 [ 40.  50.  60.]
 [ 40.  50.  60.]
 [ 40.  50.  60.]
 [ 40.  50.  60.]
 [ 40.  50.  60.]]

ZZ [[  3878.   3712.   3548.]
 [  4636.   4298.   4064.]
 [  5489.   5123.   4707.]
 [  6483.   6004.   5529.]
 [  7616.   7030.   6434.]
 [  8844.   8161.   7506.]
 [ 10245.   9503.   8716.]
 [ 11865.  11004.  10070.]]

Comment: These are the matrices for XX, YY, and ZZ
-8 is between -5 and -10; 53 between 50 and 60.
The returned value should be between ZZ [2,2] and ZZ [3,1] == 4707 and 6004.
Not higher than 6004, my bad ;-)

Comment: The returned value 2616.35 for u = -8 and v = 53 is neither the smallest nor the highest value in ZZ ...

Answer (score 0):

Let's plot the sample with a fixed `YY=40` value:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

i = 0
plt.plot(XX[i], ZZ[i],'bo')
plt.xlabel('XX[0]')
plt.ylabel('ZZ[0]')
plt.show()
```

[image: sample at YY=40]

the fitted function with a fixed `y` value:

```
x = np.arange(start=-25, stop=10, step=0.1)
for y in [40, 50, 53]:
    z = fnc(x, y, pfit)
    plt.plot(x, z, label='y=' + str(y))
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('z')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

It looks weird the `y=53` curve is so low.

Although it becomes clear on the on the other axis: look at the plot of the fitted function with a fixed `x` value:

```
y = np.arange(start=40, stop=60, step=0.1)
for x in [-10, -8, -5]:
    z = fnc(x, y, pfit)
    plt.plot(y, z, label='x=' + str(x))
plt.xlabel('y')
plt.ylabel('z')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

On that axis, it's clearly overfitting.  It's as if in 1D, we fitted a polynomial of degree `3` passing through only `3` points.   Perhaps you could increase the number of data points on that axis?

by the way

```
x = np.transpose(np.array([-25.0,-20.0,-15.0,-10.0,-5.0,0.0,5.0,10.0]))
```

is unnecessary, replace it with

```
x = np.array([-25.0,-20.0,-15.0,-10.0,-5.0,0.0,5.0,10.0])
```

Comment: Thanks alot for ur tip!
That was a specific dataset of temperatures and capacities, I'm looking for another one that has more values of temperatures at the y-achsis and will let you know right away...

Comment: @Muho903 perhaps you could also reduce the complexity of your function on the y axis, too. Degree 3 for the `x`, degree 2 for the `y`.